# Mute mic button not working on HP ENVY 13 x360 (from 2020)

Tags: drivers, hp

On hp 13 envy x360 there is a button on the keyboard which pressed should disable mic inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `90-internal-keyboard.hwdb` file in `/etc/udev/hwdb.d`:

```bsh
touch /etc/udev/hwdb.d/90-internal-keyboard.hwdb
```

Then put this into it:

```bsh
evdev:input:b0011v0001p0001eAB41*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_82=f20
```

After that run this:

```bsh
sudo systemd-hwdb update
```

and reboot.

Should work now (altho I still dontk now how to make the LED work). I solved this thanks to my post on manjaro forum:
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-map-fn-f8-to-f20-key-so-that-mic-muting-works-hp-envy-x360/49309/17

But this solution works on other distros 2, for example PopOS